# Trouble with making xquery function recursive

Tags: xquery

I'm having some difficulty with making a function I've written recursive.  I need to be able to turn this xml:

```
<entry ref="22">
    <headword>abaishen</headword>
    <part_of_speech> v. </part_of_speech>
    <variant>abeishen</variant>
    <variant>abaissen</variant>
    <variant>abeisen</variant>
    <variant>abashen</variant>
    <variant>abasshen</variant>
    <variant>abassen</variant>
    <variant>abeeshen</variant>
    <variant>abesen</variant>
    <variant>abessen</variant>
    <variant>abaished</variant>
    <variant>-et</variant>
    <variant>-it</variant>
    <variant>abaisht</variant>
    <variant>abaist</variant>
    <variant>abasht</variant>
    <variant>abast</variant>
</entry>
```

Into this XML -- essentially replacing the ending of any entry that begins with an "-" with the stem of the last complete entry:

```
 <entry ref="22">
        <headword>abaishen</headword>
        <variant>abeishen</variant>
        <variant>abaissen</variant>
        <variant>abeisen</variant>
        <variant>abashen</variant>
        <variant>abasshen</variant>
        <variant>abassen</variant>
        <variant>abeeshen</variant>
        <variant>abesen</variant>
        <variant>abessen</variant>
        <variant>abaished</variant>
        <variant>abaishet</variant>
        <variant>abaishit</variant>
        <variant>abaisht</variant>
        <variant>abaist</variant>
        <variant>abasht</variant>
        <variant>abast</variant>
        <part_of_speech> v. </part_of_speech>
    </entry>
```

The issue I'm running into is that second entry, the -it one, returns "abaishet" with the code I currently have:

```
declare function local:hyphen-replace($f) {
let $j :=
   if (substring($f/text(), 1, 1) = "-") then
      let $ending := substring-after($f/text(),"-")
      let $ending-length := string-length($ending)
      let $previous := $f/preceding-sibling::*[1]
      let $previous-length := string-length($previous)
      return
           if (substring($previous/text(), 1, 1) = "-") then
               local:hyphen-replace($previous)
           else
               element {name($f)} {concat(substring($previous,1,($previous-length - $ending-length)),$ending)}   
 else
     $f
return $j
};

declare function local:verbCheck($nodes as node()*) as node()* {

    let $d := $nodes/part_of_speech
    let $s := functx:siblings($d)
    let $p := for $node in $nodes
                return
                    let $d := $node/part_of_speech
                    let $s := functx:siblings($d)
                    return
                        if ($d/text() = " v. ") then
                            for $f in $s
                                let $j := 
                                    local:hyphen-replace($f)
                            return ($j)


                        else
                            <empty/>

    return
      ($p,$d)
};

<list>
    {

        let $collection := concat($collection, '?select=*.xml')
        let $q := collection($collection)
        let $v := local:buildNodes($q)

        let $entries := 
            for $n in $v
            return <entry ref="{$n/@ref}">{local:verbCheck($n)}</entry>

        return local:remove-empty-elements($entries)

    }
</list>
```

It's obvious to me that my problem is with this piece of code in `local:hypen-replace`:

```
if (substring($previous/text(), 1, 1) = "-") then
                   local:hyphen-replace($previous)
```

because it's calling to the immediately previous item and replacing the "-it" node with it's information. But I don't know how to rewrite it to make it work recursively properly.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with that sample data and I have probably not understood what it represents but why do you need recursion if the task is 'essentially replacing the ending of any entry that begins with an "-" with the stem of the last complete entry'? Wouldn't `variant[starts-with(., '-')]` select all those elements you need to change and then for any of them wouldn't `preceding-sibling::variant[not(starts-with(., '-'))][1]` select the last complete entry?

Comment: I think it would in this case (the sample data is a list of words) but it's possible that there might be separate instances of the word with variants with '-' beginning them following. This, for example:
   ' <entry ref="134">
        <headword>abobbed</headword>
        <part_of_speech> ppl. as n. </part_of_speech>
        <variant>abobbeþ</variant>
        <variant>-ys</variant>
        <variant>abobet</variant>
        <variant>-at</variant>
    </entry>'
 My thought was that the way to avoid any issue would be to walk the list and apply the logic to each of the items in turn.

Comment: And which result do you need for that sample? Still not sure why you need to recurse to use a particular preceding-sibling. I have tried to put my idea into a sample with the first input at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhn and the second at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhn/1, perhaps it helps. Used `!` in there as a compact XQuery 3 syntax but in earlier versions `for .. return` could be used.